# In 'form action="?login"', what does the question mark mean?

Tags: html, forms, action

Consider:

```
<form action="?login" method="post">     <button>Login with Google</button> </form>
```

I usually see the *action* refer to a PHP or HTML file, but the "?login" stumps me.

Background information:

This is buried within the *example-google.php* file from lightopenid framework.  I've been staring at the OpenID code to use Google as a third-party OpenID provider for user login on my web site and the sample code all works.

I am trying to get a clearer picture of what the framework is doing when the user presses the login button.  I know that we must be sending a bunch of arguments to Google on this button action, but the `?login` doesn’t seem to point anywhere.

http://gitorious.org/lightopenid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question mark denotes the query string.

It will post to the current URL with a query string parameter of `login`. I am not sure how you are processing the request after you click submit (post the form), but usually it would have a value assigned to it as in `login=value`.

Comment: Thanks.  It's interesting that this is actually calls itself and checks isset($_GET['login']) to fill out the parameters... the rest of the php file is starting to make much more sense now in light of this.

Answer (score 1):

It means:

**http://whatever/the-current-page-url-is?login** (where "login" is the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)).

It is a relative-URI notation, similar to `<img src="foo.jpg">` -- note the rest of the URI was not specified explicitly.

Happy coding