# PHP send email on same page with response

Tags: php, html, email, post

Code executes but I get no error messages nor success messages, any ideas why this isn't working?

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['action'])=='submitfunc') {
    submitfunc(); 
}
else {} //show form $fromeml = "From:".$_POST['demo-email'].' \r\n';

if(isset($_POST['demo-copy'])==true){
    $ccemail = "Cc:".$_POST['demo-email'].' \r\n'; 
}
else {
    $ccemail= "Cc: \r\n";
} 

function submitfunc() {

    $to = "me@mywebsite.net";    
    $subject = "This is subject";    
    $message = $_POST['demo-name']."<br><br>";    
    $message .= $_POST['demo-message'];    
    $header = $fromeml;    
    $header = $ccemail; 
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";    
    $header .= "Content-type:    text/html\r\n";
    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);   
    if( $retval == true ) {
        echo <strong>"Message sent successfully...";</strong>    
    } 
    else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";    
    }  
}


?>
```

Also, here is the form HTML code in the body above. I used name as the function to look for in the post variable.

```
                    <form method="post" action="?action=submitfunc">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u$(3)">
                                <input type="text" name="demo-name" id="demo-name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u$ 12u$(3)">
                                <input type="email" name="demo-email" id="demo-email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="12u$">
                                <div class="select-wrapper">
                                    <select name="demo-category" id="demo-category">
                                        <option value="">- Category -</option>
                                        <option value="1">Interested in a Quote for a new website</option>
                                        <option value="2">HELP!!!  Technical Issue</option>
                                        <option value="3">Maitenance Quote for existing website</option>
                                        <option value="4">General Question</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u 12u$(2)">
                                <input type="radio" id="demo-priority-low" name="demo-priority" checked>
                                <label for="demo-priority-low">Low Priority</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u 12u$(2)">
                                <input type="radio" id="demo-priority-normal" name="demo-priority">
                                <label for="demo-priority-normal">Normal Priority</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u$ 12u(2)">
                                <input type="radio" id="demo-priority-high" name="demo-priority">
                                <label for="demo-priority-high">High Priority</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u$(2)">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="demo-copy" name="demo-copy">
                                <label for="demo-copy">Email me a copy of this message</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u$ 12u$(2)">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="demo-human" name="demo-human" >
                                <label for="demo-human">I am a human and not a robot</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="12u$">
                                <textarea name="demo-message" id="demo-message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="12u$">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
                                    <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
```

Comment: Are you running locally?

Comment: do you get the email?

Comment: I do not get the email using this, I did when it was on a separate page and was able to call the generic function with plain strings and get an email so I know it has to do with my code and not my config

Comment: Is it in the code itself, so upon submit?

Comment: Yes, this php is underneath the body but reading elsewhere I expected that it would run based on the ...n="?action=submitfunc">

Comment: Add an echo in the function, to see if it gets there, just to be safe. I never use `?` in my form tag, so not entirely sure. Maybe add a php self to the action Your code does look fine.

Comment: Does `mail` work with known good values?

Comment: I only tested the [bare code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm) as a template in a separate php file and it worked fine,  I could have passed the post variables to this seperate file but I wanted to keep the user on the same page and have a JS alert that form was submitted.

Comment: Else use `if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)){echo "message send";}`instead of assigning variable to check if its true. Now it just runs within the statement, getting inmediatly a result instead of putting it in a variable. Less code for same result is better.

Comment: Have you checked your MTA logs?

Comment: @Dorvalla learned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825254/form-action-login-what-does-the-question-mark-mean) that the ? denotes the beginning of a query so I suppose its meaningless   I'll try to start over and work my way in reverse with the seperate page

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it on my own using a different version which essentially sets the form action to blank and triggers on isset($_POST['submit']){, like so:

```
<?php 



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "my@emladdress.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['demo-email']; // this is the senders Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['demo-name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['demo-priority'].label;
    $subject = "Form submission for ".$_POST['demo-category'];
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission for ".$_POST['demo-category'];
    $message = "<h1>".$first_name . "</h1>" . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['demo-message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['demo-message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    }


?>
```

This version worked with the form above and sets the email to html which is convenient and all from one page!

Comment: So you just post incorrect formaction in original question? Why you didn't debug `$_POST` contents?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, the `<strong>` open and close tags are outside of the echo command:

```
echo <strong>"Message sent successfully...";</strong>
```

Should be:

```
echo "<strong>Message sent successfully...</strong>";
```

Also I would recommend turning on error messages while debugging:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: ok I changed this value as you suggested and it didnt change anything

Comment: @Frankenmint So you're still not getting *any* text out? What about error messages?

Comment: nope same as before about to try Dorvalla's Suggestion now