# What is the meaning of ? (question mark) in a URL string?

Tags: html, jsp, url

What is the difference between using

```
href="../usermanagement/search_user.jsp?"
```

and

```
href="../usermanagement/search_user.jsp?pagename=navigation"
```

in file `navigation.jsp`?

Comment: It’s called [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: Please go through this . This has the Answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825254/form-action-login-what-does-the-question-mark-mean>?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Its name is *[query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)*. After the question mark you can pass key-value pairs and use them server-side.

Answer (score 13):

It is a query to pass paramters.  `?pagename=navigation` passes the value 'navigation' to the `pagename` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> The question mark ("?", ASCII 3F hex) is used to delimit the boundary
> between the URI of a queryable object, and a set of words used to
> express a query on that object. When this form is used, the combined
> URI stands for the object which results from the query being applied
> to the original object.

Source: [w3.org - syntax for URIs as used in the WorldWide Web initiative](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html#:%7E:text=Query%20strings,applied%20to%20the%20original%20object.)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we want to pass some parameter to JSP then we simply append "?" question mark after the JSP URL, and after that we mentioned the parameter name and its value.

"`../usermanagement/search_user.jsp?`" means you did not get any parameter on this JSP file.

"`../usermanagement/search_user.jsp?pagename=navigation`" with this URL you can get the value of the *pagename* parameter on JSP as by using this syntax:

```
String pagenNameValue=request.getParameter("pagename");
```

You will get "navigation" as the *pageNameValue* parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

The href="../usermanagement/search_user.jsp?pagename=navigation" is a GET Method and will pass a key : pagename with value : navigation via URL.

Whereas href="../usermanagement/search_user.jsp? is a POST method and doesn't pass information about its variables via URL.

check out [Difference between GET and POST method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: The presence of a query string doesn't say anything about the HTTP method being used. You can make GET requests with or without query strings. You can make POST requests with or without query strings.

Comment: The reference you use, W3Schools, is awful. In this case it is (incorrectly) conflating how a browser encodes form data when the `type` attribute is set to GET or POST with the HTTP methods themselves.