# What is happening in these lines?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to get what is happening in these lines of code.

What is the meaning of this line `href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\"` and why those `\"\"` are used and why the `?` is used after `.php`

```
echo 
    "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> |
    <a 
        href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" 
        onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\"
    >Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: \" are used to make string quotes in a string ( its called escaping ) the ? is jsut a part of the url that separates the url  from its query parameters (no php evaluation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes are there as escape characters to avoid clashes between the embedded double quotes and the surrounding double quotes. Without the escape characters, the first embedded double quote would be considered as the closing quote for the outer double quote, and you would end up with something unexpected.

So basically this:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a>...
```

Will be `echo`ed as (assuming that `$res[id]` has a value of `'foo'`):

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=foo">Edit</a>
```

When it comes to the question mark (`?`), that's a very basic URL functionality that indicates the beginning of a *query string*. The key/value pairs that are placed after the question mark are basically passed to the server. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041449/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-url-string) for more information.