# Rails hitting wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made GET request with the following url in postman

`localhost:8091/trade/search?side=SELL`

#### Expected behavior

Rails should have triggered searchTrade action
`get '/trade/search/:commodity/:side/:counterparty/:location' => 'tradeservice#searchTrade'`

#### Actual behavior

Rails misinterpreted the route as: 
`match '/trade/:id', to: 'tradeservice#getTradeById', via: :get`

#### Logs

[image]

#### System configuration

**Rails version**:
5.1.7
**Ruby version**:
2.3.3.p222

This is definitely a bug, how do i fix this ??

Comment: Could you please share what's in your routes.rb?


Seems like `match '/trade/:id'` is used because it is located above `get '/trade/search/:commodity/:side/:counterparty/:location'`.


Also, if you send params using `?side=SELL`, then you don't need the `:commodity/:side/:counterparty/:location` part.

Comment: The one which is getting called is located above the one which is not getting called.              How do i fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified [(source)](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).
`/trade/search` matches both `/trade/search` and `/trade/:id` since `:id` is a param.

The fix would be to place

```
get '/trade/search/:commodity/:side/:counterparty/:location' => 'tradeservice#searchTrade'
```

above

```
match '/trade/:id', to: 'tradeservice#getTradeById', via: :get
```

You might also want to make your endpoint look like this:

```
get '/trade/search' => 'tradeservice#searchTrade'
```

since you pass the params in [the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041449/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-url-string) (`?side=SELL`) rather than in the path.