# Why is there question mark after url?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've created route

```
 Route::get('/files/{file}/edit', 'FilesController@edit')->middleware(['file_owner'])->name('files.edit');
```

Code from middleware:

```
$file = $request->route('file');
      if($file->owner_id === auth()->user()->id){
          return $next($request);
      }
```

When I enter this route from my view

```
<form action="{{route('files.edit', $file->id)}}" >
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit file</button>
</form>
```

Link I get looks like this: `http://testproject.local/files/17/edit?`
It doesn't affect functionality, but it is really interesting for my, what is the reason of question mark appearing here?

Answer (score 2):

The default method of `<form>` is GET, which means delivering values via the url, which works like

`example.com?key=value`.

You have no values assigned, but the method remains, appending the ?.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` signifies the beginning of Query Parameters.

When you have a `<form>` without the `method=""` attribute, it performs a `GET` request when submitted. All `<input>`, `<select>`, etc. elements are appended to the URL in the form of query params:

```
https://www.example.com?name=whatever&something=another...
```

Since you don't have any `<input>` or `<select>` elements in your `<form>`, it's simply appending a `?` to show you don't have any.

Again, this doesn't affect functionality, but does raise the question; do you need a `<form>` for this? You can simply use an anchor `<a href="">...</a>` to handle a simple `GET` request without Query Params:

```
<a href="{{ route('files.edit', $file->id) }}">Edit File</a>
```

And this will take you to the route `http://testproject.local/files/17/edit`, without the `?` appended.

Answer (score 1):

Because the form's method is `GET`, which means the form data is appended to the action as a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). But since you don't have any inputs in the form, only a `?` is appended.

Answer (score 1):

[same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041449/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-url-string)

You are sending HTTP request, GET method, where you can pass parameters and values in url after question mark like url?key=value and then process the input server-side. You don't have any inputs in your form, so there is nothing after the question mark.