# How to pass `?` with url in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, special-characters

I am passing comments through the `GET` method, which contains special characters including `?`. I am using the following code in route.

```
Route::get('CustRequest/{id}/{comment}', 'ApprovalController@CustomerRequest')->where('comment', '(.*)');
```

It working well for other special characters except for `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `?` from the URL to `%3F` which is URL encode for question mark(?).

The question mark is a part of [URI generic syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) which consists of a hierarchical sequence of five components:

```
URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
```

The question mark is the generic syntax to separate path and query string and you can not change that syntax. So change the `?` from the URL to `%3F` is a must.

Long text in the path is not best practice, you should change the comment from the path to query string, an example to `domain/custrequest/id/?comment=blabla+http://dom.main/?ex=sss` and get it from the controller as `request()->comment`  you can get `?` data after the first question mark.

another reference: [What is a question mark in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041449/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-url-string)

Comment: Thank you for your reply..Actually comments are given by end users.That's the problem.Where should I encode using %3F?

Comment: can you provide an example code to go to that URL? from database or what?

Comment: Thank you.Issue solved.Replacing ? with %3F using jquery replace function.