# Meaning of ? in URL - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax

I have come across weird issue while migrating our project of .Net framework 3.5 to .Net framework 4.6.1. We have used update panel extensively in the project so after migration pages containing UpdatePanel were affected.

1. Response.Redirect was not working if control(like button) is in repeater encapsulated in UpdatePanel and trying to redirect to another page. This was throwing error - **"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed."**
2. User controls in page encapsulated by UpdatePanel was also throwing same errors.

After scratching head for many hours, we found that if pages is access by URL containing "?", no above errors are occured and page works perfectly without error. But if we access page containing UpdatePanel withoug "?" at end of URL. Page start throwing above problem. I am trying this in local IIS in DEV environment.

http://localhost:1003/Test.aspx - **NOT WORKING** and throwing above errors.
http://localhost:1003/Test.aspx? - **WORKING fine.**

I do not understand the reason behind this behaviour of .Net

Could someone explain me the rationale behind this? and what could be missing/magical in this.

Comment: refer this links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825254/form-action-login-what-does-the-question-mark-mean%3E

Comment: Since in the case when you did not have a ? in the URL, the server has thrown an exception, it is highly probable that you have a server-side code which acts differently if you have a question mark from the case when you do not have one. Try removing the question mark and looking into the details you might find via stacktrace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041449/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-url-string  this also same like your question